# Understanding a comment of the maximal function in Stein's Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis

I'm trying to understand a comment regarding the maximal function in the first chapter of Stein's *[Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691080796/singular-integrals-and-differentiability-properties-of-functions-pms)* (emphases mine):

> In contrast with the case $p>1$, when $p=1$ the mapping $f\mapsto M(f)$ is not bounded on $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Thus if $f$ is not identically zero $Mf$ is never integrable on all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. **This can be seen by** making the **simple** observation that $Mf(x)\ge c|x|^{-n}$, for $|x|\ge 1$.

Here the maximal function is defined as follows:
$$
M(f)(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|\,dy\
$$
[Added: where $B(x,r)$ is the ball of radius $r$, centered at $x$ and $m(B(x,r))$ denotes its Lebesgue measure.]

Could anyone show that how the "simple" observation is true? (I don't see why it is true even when $n=1$.)

Comment: Can you clarify what the $B(x,r)$ notation means? Also “simple” usually means “tedious to type up”. Also what does the $m$ mean? Mass of some ball with some radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observation is simple ,but simple for Stein..:p

Ipressume that $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Now if $f$ is not zero a.e then  $m(\{|f|>0\})>0$

So exists $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m(\{|f| \geq \frac{1}{m}\})>0$

By inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure, for $E_m=\{|f| \geq \frac{1}{m}\}$ exists a compact set $K \subseteq E_m$ such that $m(K)>0$

> This can be proved by writing $E_m=\bigcup_n (E_m \cap [-n,n])$ etc.

Now note that $K \subseteq B(0,M)$ for some $M>0$

So $\forall |x| \geq M$ we have that $K \subseteq B(x,|x|+M)$ thus  $$M(f)(x) \geq \frac{1}{(|x|+M)^d} \int_K|f(y)|dy \geq \frac{1}{(2|x|)^d} \frac{1}{m}m(K)$$

You can adjust this idea to prove the statement for $\forall |x| \geq 1$

Comment: From $\|f\|_1=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{B(0,R)}|f|$ one can jump directly to $m(B(0,M))>0$ for some $M>0$. No need to evoke the inner regularity of $m$.

Comment: @MaoWao  always the measure of a ball is positive..i think you have a typo..you meant to write something else

Comment: You're right, I meant $\int_{B(0,M)}|f|>0$, which is enough for the estimate you make in the end.

Comment: @MaoWao  Ok yes..so from this exists $A \subset B(0,M)$ with positive measure  such that $|f|>0$ is $A$..so again after this i can find $m \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $m(A \cap \{f>1/m\})>0$ e.t.c...This is what you mean?

Comment: You can do this, but my point is that you don't even have to go there. Let $c=\int_{B(0,M)}|f|$. Then your very argument show $Mf(x)\geq c/(|x|+M)^d$, which is (more or less) the claim. You just need $c$ to be positive, but that can always be arranged for $M$ large enough, as mentioned above.

Comment: @MaoWao but the maximal function considers balls with center $x$ so i have to integrate with respect to such ball..can you elaborate a bit more,to understand you completely?

Comment: It's really the same argument as in the middle of your last inequality chain: Since $B(0,M)\subset B(x,|x|+M)$, we have $\int_{B(x,|x|+M)}|f|\geq \int_{B(0,M)}|f|$.

Comment: @MaoWao oh yes.. i understand now..so i do not need to involve any compact or bounded subset of $B(0,M)$ since $B(0,M) \subseteq B(x,|x|+M)$