# Showing $Mf \not\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$ be such that $\int \vert f \vert dm>0$. Prove there exists $c \in (0,\infty)$ such that for all $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ with $\vert \vert x \vert \vert \geq 1$ one has

$$Mf \geq \frac{c}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert^n}.$$

Use this to deduce $Mf \not\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

**Attempt:**

We suppose by way of contradiction that for every $c \in (0,\infty)$, there is an $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ with $\vert \vert x \vert \vert \geq 1$ that

$$Mf< \frac{c}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert^n}. \space \space (*)$$

But we know there is an $R \in (0,\infty)$ such that

$$\int_{B_R(0)}\vert f \vert dm >0.$$

But $(*)$ implies $Mf$ is zero but this cannot be as the supremum of a set with positive values need be positive, by definition so we conclude

$$Mf \geq \frac{c}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert^n}.$$

how do I conclude $Mf \not\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$. I thought about integrating both sides but idk what to do with the $\frac{1}{\vert \vert x \vert \vert^n}$ if I integrate.

Comment: why the downvote? This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: What is $M$ supposed to be?

Comment: $Mf:=\sup\{\frac{1}{m(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} \vert f \vert dm\}$ @stange

Comment: the maximal functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding a comment of the maximal function in Stein's Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391553/understanding-a-comment-of-the-maximal-function-in-steins-singular-integrals-an)

Comment: For the last part you can pass to spherical coordinates to get $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{\Vert x\Vert^p} dx = \omega_n \int_0^\infty r^{n-1} \frac{1}{r^p} dr,$$ where $\omega_n$ is the area of the sphere in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: If $\|f\|_1>0$, then there is $a>0$ such that $c=\int_{B(0;a)}|f|>0$. For $|x|>a$,
\begin{align} Mf(x)\geq\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x;2|x|))}\int_{B(x;2|x|)}|f|\geq\frac{C_n}{|x|^n}\int_{B(0;a)}|f|=\frac{C'_n}{|x|^n}.
\end{align}
The conclusion follows from the fact that $g(x)=|x|^{-n}\mathbb{1}_{B^c(0;a)}(x)\notin L_1(\lambda_d)$ (use spherical coordinates for example).

Comment: This is a duplicate question. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3002113/121671) is another posting that deals with the OP's problem